# Get nearest node following segment

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

I am trying to get the nearest node from a point(Id 1) . The coordinates (lat/long) are input by an user . I am using some functions like *pgr_nearest_node()* or *get_nearest_node()* from [get_nearest_node function reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1avk.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1avk.png): http://www.sqlexamples.info/SPAT/postgis_nearest_point.htm. The Problem Is that the point take the nearest node using straight line between them(928-3670-317-929 Id nodes). How can i get the nearest node in the network ? . I am thinking about to use pgr_dijkstra function but it need to a source id so i return to functions commented before.

[image: The 1 Id point is the input point.When i use the functions before, the result is Id 928 from my net_vertices_pgr. The objective is to get as result nearest node from Id1 ,the 317 Id node]

Comment: Have your set up your network for pg_routing? In other words, are the columns source and targets populated? In that case you could use st_distance to get the nearest line on the network, and then select the closest of source or target for that line...

Comment: Hello. Yes , i have two tables **net_city** and **net_city_vertices_pgr**. Net_city have source and target columns in addition to more data like ;osm_id.osm_name and the source,target coordinates(lat/long).Net_city_vertices_pgr have id and the_geom columns in adiction four more columns. What you are asking is interesting, i am going to try. I will comment on the result.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hello. Following the comments indicated I obtained the following expression. As results i get d as distance,source and target of closest line .But unable to resolve the last step, select the closest point of the line selected node.
`SELECT (ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326),(geom_way))) as d,source,target from segment_table order by d limit 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps there's a more elegant way, but the following query should work:

```
with nearest_line as -- put the query to get the nearest line in a CTE
                     -- use the CTE twice

(select  source, target from segment_table order by 
 (ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326) limit 1) 


select id from

-- A union query to get the source and target ids from vertices
(select id,the_geom from segment_table_vertices_pgr p1
inner join nearest_line l on source = id
union all
select id,the_geom from segment_table_vertices_pgr p1
inner join nearest_line l on target = id) a
-- sort it by distance from the point and return the one record
order by  st_distance_sphere(the_geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lon,lat),4326)) limit 1
```

Comment: Hello. It works very well. I've just added a parameter to calculate the distance to the line(geom column of segment_table-**geom_way**-) . Thank you very much .

`(select  source, target from net_jaen order by 
 (ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326),geom_way)) limit 1`